# Meta data not saved on save_post

Tags: save-post

When I try to save my post after inserting it via an external php script, it returns my the post id, but it's not able to retrieve the post meta created in the database.

I am getting an array having an `_encloseme` parameter when retrieving through `get_post_meta` and I know it means that the enclosure process is still running and metadata is not yet saved.

Please can anyone tell help me get the meta data when I use `save_post`.

```
Array(
    _encloseme=>1;
    )
```

Comment: You can use get_post_meta($postid) to get all meta data saved w.r.t to that particular post.
If it doesn't return anything means there are issues in saving meta data, not in retrieving.

Comment: I am able to see the metadata in the wp_postmeta table but i am not able to retreive it while save_post is going on..i used both get_post_meta as well as sql query but i can this _encloseme param which says that the saving process is going on..so can you suggest some alternative...